# How can I default select all Multiselect picklist values?

Tags: visualforce, multi-select

I have a requirement where I have to default selected all values on visual force page. I have searched everywhere but I still have no lead to work on it.

Would someone please advise how to do that using controller and visual force page please .

Comment: A multi-select choice field can have only one default value.

Comment: @raym0nd I understand that is standard salesforce, but can we not even achieve this using apex even?

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: See [Pre select multiple option in select option](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116802/pre-select-multiple-option-in-select-option) asked and answered in the last hour.

Answer (score 0):

In your page do something like

```
<apex:selectList size="5" id="selectRev" value="{!selValue}" multiselect="true" >
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!MultiValues}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Controller:

```
public List<SelectOption> getMultiValues() {
List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
options.add(new SelectOption('value1','value1'));
return options;
}


Public string[] getselValue(){
   //Where c.Test_Multi__c would be the name of the field you are storing the value in.

   if (c.Test_Multi__c!=null)
    return c.Test_Multi__c.split(';');

   else
     return null;
}

public void setselValue(string[] vals){
   c.Test_Multi__c=string.join(vals,';');
}
```

Comment: hey I was about to message here. I have implemented this code. But result is strange I only see one box of multiselect. Normally there are two box. One for Available and one for Choosen. But here I only see one box. Don't understand why ?

Comment: also that is still not default selected all.

Comment: raym0nd -- check out [etiquette discussion](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/what-sfse-etiquette-should-be-followed) on solicitation of marking answers as 'solutions'